# Error in UIButton's IBAction

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, addsubview

I would like to show `UIViewController` **MyViewController** by tapping at `UICollectionViewCell` and then close it.

So, in my **didSelectItemAtIndexPath**:

```
CGRect myFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
MyViewController *myController = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];
myController.view.frame = myFrame;
[self.view addSubview:myController.view];
```

it works!

In **MyViewController** I have `UIButton` which is linked to:

```
- (IBAction)close:(id)sender {
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

But when I tap to the button I have this instead of **close** method call:

[image]

**EDIT**: Thank to **calampunay** and **Manohar**

Problem solved. But I have replaced both **addSubview** and **removeFromSuperview** to AppDelagate, in which declared **MyViewController** as a property. The reason is - I want to close **MyViewController** even if I will jump to other tab (I have TabBar in my App) or something else.

It would better if **MyViewController** will be close even if I tap in other place (not in it's frame).

Comment: your object is released, i guess. check for strong or retain.

Comment: [self.view removeFromSuperview]; y your remove .. then wat will be remove.. do u know?

Answer (score 0):

Declare in .h file

```
MyViewController *myController;
```

in .m

```
myController = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];
myController.view.frame = myFrame;
[self.view addSubview:myController.view];

- (IBAction)close:(id)sender 
{
    [myController.view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: didn't understand. **addSubview** is in root controller, but **removeFromSuperview** is in MyController. Where should I declare it?

Answer (score 0):

In you root/parent view controller, declare myController as property:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) MyViewController *mycontroller;
```

In your **didSelectItemAtIndexPath**, do this instead:

```
CGRect myFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
self.myController = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];
myController.view.frame = myFrame;
[self.view addSubview:myController.view];
```

The problem is, your `myController` is already released when the button tap action happened, and it tries to call the `close:` method to a released object(myController).